# How to paint over a complex object

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I do have a fairly complex figure painted on canvas. (~ 1000 polygons). The repainting time for all of them is about 1 sec (very slow). Now I need to let user move over that figure and display a vertical and horizontal lines  (cross hairs) from under mouse position. What is the best technique to paint only those 2 lines without going over all polygons and repaint everything at every mouse move.

Thx

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem to have an element laid out over the canvas.

Comment: I think having an element on top of canvas isn't going to end well.

Comment: @Eugen Are you using any higher level canvas library?

Comment: @Eugen I have used [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) in past and its fairly easily possible to have layering with mouse events. With that you won't have to redraw everything on canvas all the time.

Comment: @bits Why not? What issues do you anticipate?

Comment: I try do not use any 3rd party library, trying to reduce dependencies to the minimum. So, the only way would be to have another layer (canvas) on top of the one with a complex figure?

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is broken.**

You want to draw lines and move them without touching the underlying painting.
In the good old days, the method used was to paint with xor composition on top of the drawing, and draw the same pattern (here it would be lines) the same way at the same location to remove it from the screen, again without touching the real painting.

I tried to use this method with the code below to test it out, but it doesn't seem to work. Hopefully, someone with a better knowledge of canvas and js will come forth and fix things up.

```
function onmousemove(e){
  // firt run
  var tcanvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
  var tcontext = tcanvas.getContext("2d");
  var pos = {x : e.clientX, y : e.clientY, 
             w : tcanvas.width, h : tcanvas.height };
  var comp = tcontext.globalCompositeOperation;
  var paintline = function (p){
      tcontext.save();

      tcontext.lineWidth = 1;
      tcontext.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
      tcontext.fillStyle = "#000000";

      tcontext.moveTo(0,p.y);
      tcontext.lineTo(p.w,p.y);
      tcontext.moveTo(p.x,0);
      tcontext.lineTo(p.x,p.h);
      tcontext.stroke();

      tcontext.restore();
  };

  tcontext.save();
  paintline(pos);
  tcontext.restore();

  var next = function(e){
      var comp = tcontext.globalCompositeOperation;
      paintline(pos);
      pos = {x : e.clientX, y : e.clientY, 
             w : tcanvas.width, h : tcanvas.height };
      paintline(pos);
  };
  document.onmousemove = next;
}


(function draw_stuff(){
    // setup canvas
    var tcanvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
    var tcontext = tcanvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw square
    tcontext.fillStyle = "#FF3366";
    tcontext.fillRect(15,15,70,70);

    // set composite property
    tcontext.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';

    // draw text
    tcontext.fillStyle="#0099FF";
    tcontext.font = "35px sans-serif";
    tcontext.fillText("test", 22, 25);
    // draw circle
    tcontext.fillStyle = "#0099FF";
    tcontext.beginPath();
    tcontext.arc(75,75,35,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    tcontext.fill();
    document.onmousemove = onmousemove; 
})();
```

Also, there are problem with compositing depending on the browser.

Comment: I know about XOR, I used same technique. But I'd like to achieve same behavior as in WPF. There you just move the object, not using any XOR stuff. Plus you cannot use XOR technique for text.

Comment: I don't know anything about WPF.